# device_token_auth token generation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, devise-token-auth

I have 'device_token_auth' (0.1.36) gem for the token generation in my ROR web application. I am not much aware of the functionality of this gem. Suddenly an issue come as

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

And the backtrace picture is as,
[image]

The source code for the same gem,
[device_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/v0.1.36/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb)

After looking to the code it can be interpreted that `tokens[client_id]` or `tokens` is missing but since the caller's `app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:75 in update_auth_header` method `update_auth_header` is handeling this case already.

Can someone tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the version you are using is a bit old which is a known issue as per [this](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/286). It was fixed in later versions. Try upgrading the gem and let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Which version nearest to the current ('0.1.36') version doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In config/application.rb after "class Application < Rails::Application" add the following 2 lines:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

Comment: Since I have API for Mobile app hence do not deal with cookies.